# UNPIVOT Data with over Fourty Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unpivot

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @T table
( ClientID INT, Dated DateTime,Value1 varchar(10),Value2 varchar(10),
  Value3 varchar(10),Value4 varchar(10),Value5 varchar(10),Value6 varchar(10)
  ,Value7 varchar(10),Value8 varchar(10),Value9 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T values
(1,'2014-01-06 16:27:47.440','High','Low','Medium','High','Medium','Low','Medium','High','Low'),
(2,'2014-01-06 16:27:47.440','Medium','High','Low','Medium','High','Low','Medium','Low','Medium'),
(1,'2014-01-01 16:27:47.440','Medium','Low','High','Medium','Low','Medium','High','Low','Medium')

SELECT * FROM @T

╔══════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ClientID ║          Dated          ║ Value1 ║ Value2 ║ Value3 ║ Value4 ║ Value5 ║ Value6 ║ Value7 ║ Value8 ║ Value9 ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║        1 ║ 2014-06-01 16:27:47.440 ║ High   ║ Low    ║ Medium ║ High   ║ Medium ║ Low    ║ Medium ║ High   ║ Low    ║
║        2 ║ 2014-06-01 16:27:47.440 ║ Medium ║ High   ║ Low    ║ Medium ║ High   ║ Low    ║ Medium ║ Low    ║ Medium ║
║        1 ║ 2014-01-01 16:27:47.440 ║ Medium ║ Low    ║ High   ║ Medium ║ Low    ║ Medium ║ High   ║ Low    ║ Medium ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

**My Query**

```
SELECT TOP 1 
        B.Value1 AS Historical_Value1, A.Value1 AS Recent_Value1
    ,   B.Value2 AS Historical_Value2, A.Value2 AS Recent_Value2
    ,   B.Value3 AS Historical_Value3, A.Value3 AS Recent_Value3
    ,   B.Value4 AS Historical_Value4, A.Value4 AS Recent_Value4
    ,   B.Value5 AS Historical_Value5, A.Value5 AS Recent_Value5
    ,   B.Value6 AS Historical_Value6, A.Value6 AS Recent_Value6
    ,   B.Value7 AS Historical_Value7, A.Value7 AS Recent_Value7
    ,   B.Value8 AS Historical_Value8, A.Value8 AS Recent_Value8
    ,   B.Value9 AS Historical_Value9, A.Value9 AS Recent_Value9
FROM @T A INNER JOIN @T B
ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID
WHERE B.Dated < A.Dated
ORDER BY A.Dated DESC, B.Dated DESC
```

As you can see I am pulling out The lastest Recordings for all the values and the recording recorded prior to that. Recent Values and Historical Values respectively. 
 Which returns me Data back in the following format.

**Current OUTPUT**

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Historical_Value1 ║ Recent_Value1 ║ Historical_Value2 ║ Recent_Value2 ║ Historical_Value3 ║ Recent_Value3 ║ Historical_Value4 ║ Recent_Value4 ║ Historical_Value5 ║ Recent_Value5 ║ Historical_Value6 ║ Recent_Value6 ║ Historical_Value7 ║ Recent_Value7 ║ Historical_Value8 ║ Recent_Value8 ║ Historical_Value9 ║ Recent_Value9 ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Medium            ║ High          ║ Low               ║ Low           ║ High              ║ Medium        ║ Medium            ║ High          ║ Low               ║ Medium        ║ Medium            ║ Low           ║ High              ║ Medium        ║ Low               ║ High          ║ Medium            ║ Low           ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

**Desired OUTPUT**

But I would like to UNPIVOT the data so it is shown as Follows, I have seen a lot of question on SO but none of them seems to fit my requirement. Any pointer any advice is most welcome thank you.

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ Values ║ Historical ║ Recent ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ Value1 ║ High       ║ Medium ║
║ Value2 ║ Low        ║ Low    ║
║ Value3 ║ Medium     ║ High   ║
║ Value4 ║ High       ║ Medium ║
║ Value5 ║ High       ║ Medium ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform the join then UNPIVOT, or performing an UNPIVOT on both the Historical and Recent, then joining? Can you provide a link to one of the previous questions which doesn't fit your requirement and explain where/why it doesn't fit?

Comment: @user3056839 I got my current output after joining the table to itself since I want current values and 2nd recent values for a certain client. Now I couldnt figure out how can I the Desired output since data is somewhat pivoted, I reckon an UNPIVOT query can do trick but I havent really used UNPIVOT syntax in sql server not to familiar with the syntax either.

Comment: person who has downvoted this question, because its unclear what I am asking, I dont know how much more information I need to provide to make you understand what I am asking ??? do you want me to add a solution as well will be clear enough then ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one way to do it:

```
;WITH up AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM @T 
    UNPIVOT
    (
         val FOR n IN (Value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9)
    ) as pv
)
SELECT 
    A.ClientID,
    A.Dated,
    A.n as Values,
    A.val as Recent,
    B.val as History
FROM
    up as A
    JOIN up as B
        ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID
        AND A.n = B.n
WHERE B.Dated < A.Dated
ORDER BY 
    A.Dated DESC, B.Dated DESC
```